# How to stop or start system services using excel visual basic application code

Tags: vba

When i click button in excel it should start or stop specific system service. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a combination of Shell and sc.exe like:

```
Shell "sc.exe \\yourserver start servicename".
```

The service key is the service name like W3SVC. Replace start with stop to stop it.